# Find the radius of convergence of the series $y=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{p}{n} x^{n}$

Tags: calculus, summation, power-series, binomial-coefficients

Let $p\in R$ Find the radius of convergence of the series:

$$y=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{p}{n} x^{n}$$

Show that y satisfies the differential equation $(1+x)y'=py$ and initial condition $y(0)=1$

---

I'm not sure if this question has been asked, but I searched and could not find it. So I know that the radius of convergence is the radius of the largest disk that the series converges in. I'm confused by this problem in general and am unsure of where to even begin. I am looking for a clear solution and explanation to this problem.

Comment: I suppose $p$ is given. Are there any conditions on $p$ or is it just an arbitrary real?

Comment: yes! p is real, I am going to edit that right now.

Comment: It may help to include what you mean by $\binom{p}{n}$ if $p$ is real (and not an positive natural number).  If $p$ was a positive integer, then when $n>p$ you have that $\binom{p}{n}=0$... so the sum only has finitely many terms and hence converges everywhere.

Comment: @TravisJ: That's why I was asking for a precise information on $p$. See also my comment to the answer below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just the generalization of the usual binomial series:
$$ f(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0}\binom{p}{n} x^n = (x+1)^p.\tag{1} $$
$(1+x)\,f'=p\,f$ is a separable ODE, and $\frac{f'}{f}=\frac{p}{x+1}$ gives that $x=-1$ is a singularity for $f(x)$.

It is the closest singularity to the origin, hence the radius of convergence of $(1)$ is just $\color{red}{1}$.

Comment: Note that if $p$ is an integer then $\binom{p}{n}=0$ for $n >p$ and hence the sum terminates (and thus converges) for all $x$...

Comment: Clearly right, but I assumed $p\not\in\mathbb{N}$, otherwise the question is trivial.

Comment: Can this be used to find the closed form of y? @JackD'Aurizio

Comment: @Kristin: what do you read in line $(1)$?

Comment: that it is the generalization of the binomial series; which to my understanding is the closed form of this series, correct?

Comment: I suppose I'm a little confused @JackD'Aurizio because the wording of the question I'm reading is: Solve the initial value problem to find y in closed form.

Comment: @Kristin: exactly, $(1+x)^p$ is defined also for non-integer $p$s by the solution of an ODE, if we like it. The series appearing in $(1)$ is a possible representation for such a function, and not by chance it is a generalization of the usual binomial sum.

Answer (score 0):

To find the radius of convergence you can use the ratio test. Lets consider a power series 
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n$$

You can find the radius of convergence $R$ using the simplyfied formula:

$$R = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{|a_n|}{|a_{n+1}}=\lim_{n \to \infty}|\frac{\frac{p!}{n!(n-p)!}}{\frac{p!}{(n+1)!(p-n-1)!}}|=\lim_{n \to \infty}|\frac{n+1}{p-n}|=1$$

As $p \in R$ we are using the gamma function as a representation for the factorial.

Answer (score -1):

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{p}{n}x^n=\sum_{k=1}^p\binom{p}{k}x^k=(1+x)^p$$
for all $x$. Therefore the radius of convergence is $\mathbb R$.